# How to configure collectd plugin for one time execution

Tags: package-management

I want to write plugin which will collect the system startup data for the resources such as cpu,mem .Once the data is read it needs to be written over the unixsock using the collectds unixsock plugin . But this needs to be done only once in whole ignition cycle of the system. So how to configure Interval value of the collectd plugin in order to execute it only once after the system has finished startup / bootup sequence and never execute again in whole span of system ignition cycle.